# Jquery Mobile - why is scrollview/scrolling on Android so much slower than on iOS?

Tags: android, ios4, jquery-mobile, scrollview

I have developed an order entry form, which I want to use on mobile devices.

Here is the link to the [example](http://www.franckreich.de/4/members/m2.html).

The problem is:

On iOS (iPhone4G, iPad) the horizontal scrolling is super-fast. On Android (HTC Sense) it's super-slow.

I have found a [thread](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/a-fix-for-low-android-performance-remove-box-shadow) in the JQM-forum making box-shadow the culprit for slow scrolling on Android. But things don't really speed up even after removing all box-shadows.

Strangely, if I remove all input fields (2nd and 3rd list item from "sizeBox"-list, things still don't speed up.

Can someone point me to another cause?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around for a while with the example... border-radius und background-gradients slow things down considerably. A matter of finding the best looks vs. usability setup.